# How to interpret the upper/lower bound of a datapoint with confidence intervals?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, confidence-interval, t-test

Given a list of values:

```
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = list(range(100))
```

Using student t-test, I can find the confidence interval of the distribution at the mean with an alpha of 0.1 (i.e. at 90% confidence) with:

```
def confidence_interval(alist, v, itv):
    return stats.t.interval(itv, df=len(alist)-1, loc=v, scale=stats.sem(alist))

x = list(range(100))
confidence_interval(x, np.mean(x), 0.1)
```

[out]:

```
(49.134501289005009, 49.865498710994991)
```

But if I were to find the confidence interval at every datapoint, e.g. for the value `10`:

```
>>> confidence_interval(x, 10, 0.1)
(9.6345012890050086, 10.365498710994991)
```

**How should the interval of the values be interpreted?** Is it statistically/mathematical sound to interpret that at all?

Does it goes something like:

> At 90% confidence, we know that the data point `10` falls in the interval `(9.6345012890050086, 10.365498710994991)`,

aka.

> At 90% confidence, we can say that the data point falls at 10 +- 0.365...

So can we interpret the interval as some sort of a box plot of the datapoint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## In short

Your call gives the interval of confidence for the mean parameter of a normal law of unknown parameters of which you observed 100 observations with an average of 10 and a stdv of 29. It is furthermore not sound to interpret it, since your distribution is clearly not normal, and because 10 is not the observed mean.

## TL;DR

There are a lot misconceptions floating around confidence intervals, most of which seemingly stems from a misunderstanding of what we are confident about. Since there is some confusion in your understanding of confidence interval maybe a broader explanation will give a deeper understanding of the concepts you are handling, and hopefully definitely rule out any source of error.

### Clearing out misconceptions

Very briefly to set things up. We are in a situation where we want to estimate a parameter, or rather, we want to test a hypothesis for the value of a parameter parameterizing the distribution of a random variable. e.g: Let's say I have a normally distributed variable X with mean m and standard deviation sigma, and I want to test the hypothesis m=0.

#### What is a parametric test

This a process for testing a hypothesis on a parameter for a random variable. Since we only have access to observations which are concrete realizations of the random variable, it generally procedes by computing a **statistic** of these realizations. A statistic is roughly a function of the realizations of a random variable. Let's call this function S, we can compute S on x_1,...,x_n which are as many realizations of X.

Therefore you understand that S(X) is a random variable as well with distribution, parameters and so on! The idea is that for standard tests, S(X) follows a very well known distribution for which values are tabulated. e.g: http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/gerstman/StatPrimer/t-table.pdf

#### What is a confidence interval?

Given what we've just said, a definition for a confidence interval would be: the range of values for the tested parameter, such that if the observations were to have been generated from a distribution parametrized by a value in that range, it would not have probabilistically improbable.
In other words, a confidence interval gives an answer to the question: given the following observations x_1,...,x_n n realizations of X, can we confidently say that X's distribution is parametrized by such value. 90%, 95%, etc... asserts the level of confidence. Usually, external constraints fix this level (industrial norms for quality assessment, scientific norms e.g: for the discovery of new particles).

I think it is now intuitive to you that:

1. The higher the confidence level, the larger the confidence interval. e.g. for a confidence of 100% the confidence interval would range across all the possible values as soon as there is some uncertainty
2. For most tests, under conditions I won't describe, the more observations we have, the more we can restrain the confidence interval.

> At 90% confidence, we know that the data point 10 falls in the interval (9.6345012890050086, 10.365498710994991)

It is wrong to say that and it is the most common source of mistakes. A 90% confidence interval **never** means that the estimated parameter has 90% percent chance of falling into that interval. When the interval is computed, it covers the parameter or it does not, it is not a matter of probability anymore. **90% is an assessment of the reliability of the estimation procedure**.

#### What is a student test?

Now let's come to your example and look at it under the lights of what we've just said. You to apply a Student test to your list of observations.
First: a Student test aims at testing a hypothesis of equality between the mean m of a normally distributed random variable with **unknown** standard deviation, and a certain value m_0.

The statistic associated with this test is `t = (np.mean(x) - m_0)/(s/sqrt(n))` where x is your vector of observations, n the number of observations and s the **empirical** standard deviation. With no surprise, this follows a Student distribution.

Hence, what you want to do is:

1. compute this statistic for your sample, compute the confidence interval associated with a Student distribution with this many degrees of liberty, this **theoretical** mean, and confidence level
2. see if your computed `t` falls into that interval, which tells you if you can rule out the equality hypothesis with such level of confidence.

I wanted to give you an exercise but I think I've been lengthy enough.

To conclude on the use of `scipy.stats.t.interval`. You can use it one of two ways. Either computing yourself the t statistic with the formula shown above and check if t fits in the interval returned by `interval(alpha, df)` where df is the length of your sampling. Or you can directly call `interval(alpha, df, loc=m, scale=s)` where m is your empirical mean, and s the empirical standard deviatation (divided by sqrt(n)). In such case, the returned interval will directly be the confidence interval for the mean.

So in your case your call gives the interval of confidence for the mean parameter of a normal law of unknown parameters of which you observed 100 observations with an average of 10 and a stdv of 29. It is furthermore not sound to interpret it, beside the error of interpretation I've already pointed out, since your distribution is clearly not normal, and because 10 is not the observed mean.

### Resources

You can check out the following resources to go further.

#### wikipedia links to have quick references and an elborated overview

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution

#### To go further

http://osp.mans.edu.eg/tmahdy/papers_of_month/0706_statistical.pdf

I haven't read it but the one below seems quite good.
https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/BrownClasses/162/Handouts/StatsTests04.pdf

You should also check out p-values, you will find a lot of similarities and hopefully you understand them better after reading this post.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value#Definition_and_interpretation

Answer (score 3):

Confidence intervals are hopelessly counter-intuitive. Especially for programmers, I dare say as a programmer.

[Wikipedida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) uses a 90% confidence to illustrate a possible interpretation:

> Were this procedure to be repeated on numerous samples, the fraction of calculated confidence intervals (which would differ for each sample) that encompass the true population parameter would tend toward 90%.

In other words

1. The confidence interval provides information about a statistical parameter (such as the mean) of a sample.
2. The interpretation of e.g. a 90% confidence interval would be: If you repeat the experiment an infinite number of times 90% of the resulting confidence intervals will contain the true parameter.

Assuming the code to compute the interval is correct (which I have not checked) you can use it to calculate the confidence interval of the mean (because of the [t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-distribution), which models the *sample mean of a normally distributed population with unknown standard deviation*).

For practical purposes it makes sense to pass in the sample mean. Otherwise you are saying "**if I pretended my data had a sample mean of e.g. 10, the confidence interval of the mean would be [9.6, 10.3]**".

The particular data passed into the confidence interval does not make sense either. Numbers increasing in a range from 0 to 99 are *very* unlikely to be drawn from a normal distribution.

Comment: I think it is wrong to say "Statistically it only makes sense to pass in the sample mean", on the contrary, it makes sense to pass the value against which you want to test your hypothesis (see my answer). Besides, it is not enough to say that the t distribution models the sample mean. You have to add that the standard deviation is unknown. Finally, the values could perfectly have been generated by a normal distribution with big enough standard deviation ;).

Comment: @anis you may be right in saying it is wrong to say so... I guess it depends on what the OP actually intended to do, which is not 100% clear but I guess was based on a misconception. You hopefully clarified that in your answer. The values could have come from a normal distribution but as I wrote, this is very unlikely. May I challenge you to repeatedly draw samples from a normal distribution until you get 100 evenly spaced values? :)

Comment: With a continuous variable I wouldn't really have a chance would I :). Let me remove my downvote, I really hate doing that, but maybe you could do the changes I was saying if you agree with them.

Comment: @anis I'm happy to correct any mistakes in my posts, but firsts let's clarify the point. You clearly approach the issue from the perspective of hypothesis tests. I believe confidence intervals are useful on their own without considering hypothesis tests. What I was trying to say was that if you compute the confidence interval of the mean it does not make sense to substitute the mean with another arbitrary value. Do you disagree with this or did I phrase the statement poorly?

Comment: It is in fact the same thing. When you compute that you implicitly ask: what is a range of value for which it would have been not too unlikely to make the same observations as the ones I made, and for which I computed all that is necessary to make a student test that is: the empirical mean, the empirical std dev (which OP doesn't use, but which should be passed as the argument shape) and the degree of freedom. So I don't say it doesn't make any sense, but that one could perfectly pass another value and it still would make some sense. It is the "only makes sense" that bugs me.

Comment: I feel like I should detail more the use of interval, and what it really does, and what are the meaning of the parameters.

Comment: @anis so you agree with the part printed in bold but not with the preceding sentence. I have to admit, that is disputable and not luckily phrased. Can you suggest a better wording?